Error when starting JBPM Server 7.74.1 Community
I'm new with JBPM and I downloaded the latest Community version from official website.
enter image description here
After unzip the file I ran the standalone.bat as the page says but I'm getting some exceptions like these ones and the server is failling to start (according to website no more settings are needed, only run standalone.bat file):
17:34:16,271 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "business-central.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp.postConstruct() on org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp@6281f1a0
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp.postConstruct() on org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp@6281f1a0
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: critical problem loading the marshallers
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.errai.marshalling.client.api.exceptions.InvalidMappingException: there is no custom mapping or default no-arg constructor to map: org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftdouble.HardSoftDoubleScore

After continue trying to start then I got these logs:
17:36:48,754 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
17:36:48,828 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server response code 405
17:36:58,833 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
17:36:58,912 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server response code 405
At the end the console shows these same logs in a loop and the server doesn't start.
Do I'm missing some configurations to getting the server started?
I'm trying to start JBPM server on W11.
Thanks.
I tried to redownload again the Community version but same result.
I would like to start the community server to see how it looks and works, so would be helpful is can I get some help to know what I'm missing to get the server running.
